# How can i repeat this script many times using python

Tags: python, selenium

I am  not sure if we will use for loop here or not.

This whole script is needed to complete one task.

I wanted to repeat this script for around 100 times:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()

time.sleep(2.5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()

time.sleep(2.5)

driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()

time.sleep(2.5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
```

Comment: then use a loop probably a for loop since You can easily set the amount of loops

Comment: You want to repeat *this* script or refactor it?

Comment: Take a look at [for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to repeat this:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()

time.sleep(2.5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()

time.sleep(2.5)
```

A 100 times?

Then just do:

```
for x in range(100):
  driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()

  time.sleep(2.5)

  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()

  time.sleep(2.5)
```